# How to release possible Postgres row locks?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, locking

I ran an update statement on a large PostgreSQL table through the phpPgAdmin interface. This timed out as it ran for too long.

I can now update some rows from that table but not all. Trying to update some rows will hang.

Are the rows locked? How can I allow these rows to be updated?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What version of PostgreSQL are you running?  The following assumes 8.1.8 or later (it may apply to earlier versions too, I don't know).

I presume that you mean that phpPgAdmin timed out -- the PostgreSQL backend will take as long as it takes to complete a query/update.  In that case, it's possible that the original session is still alive and the UPDATE query is still running.  I suggest running the following query (taken from [chapter 24 of the PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/monitoring.html)) on the machine that hosts the PostgreSQL server process, to see whether the session is still alive:

```
ps auxwww|grep ^postgres
```

Several rows should appear: 1 for the `postmaster` master process, and 1 each for "writer", "stats buffer", and "stats collector" processes.  Any remaining lines are for processes serving DB connections.  These lines will contain the username and database name.

Hopefully, from that you can see whether the session you performed the original UPDATE in is still hanging around.  Although in theory you could find more detailed info by `SELECT`ing from the system view `pg_stat_activity`, by default PostgreSQL is not set up to populate the most useful fields (such as `current_query` and `query_start`).  See chapter 24 for how to enable this in the future.

If you see the session is still there, kill it.  You will need to be logged in as the user running the process (usually `postgres`) or root to do so -- if you don't run the server yourself, get your DBA to do this for you.

One more thing: for updating rows in a table, PostgreSQL avoids using locks.  Instead, it allows every writing transaction to create a new "version" of the DB, which becomes the "current version" when the transaction is committed, provided it doesn't conflict with updates made in the meantime by other transactions.  So I suspect the "hanging" you're seeing is caused by something else -- though what, I'm not sure.  (Have you checked the obvious things, like whether the disk partition containing the DB is full?)

Comment: Excellent, this worked, thank you. Note that when I killed the process that was causing the problem, that allowed some other processes to run which had been waiting for the lock to be released. This caused some further problems. I should have killed the processes marked "WAITING" when I ran ps auxwww|grep ^postgres before killing the first problem process.

Comment: "If you see the session is still there, kill it." -- For newbies, look where it says `postgres 15398 ... idle in transaction` or whatever and type `kill 15398` in Putty.

Answer (score 135):

It's possible to see the locks.

Here is a view to make it a bit easier than using pg_locks directly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.active_locks AS 
 SELECT t.schemaname,
    t.relname,
    l.locktype,
    l.page,
    l.virtualtransaction,
    l.pid,
    l.mode,
    l.granted
   FROM pg_locks l
   JOIN pg_stat_all_tables t ON l.relation = t.relid
  WHERE t.schemaname <> 'pg_toast'::name AND t.schemaname <> 'pg_catalog'::name
  ORDER BY t.schemaname, t.relname;
```

Then you just select from the view:

```
SELECT * FROM active_locks;
```

And kill it with:

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend('%pid%');
```

Other solutions:
http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Comment: There is no view or table with the name `active_locks` in Postgres. Do you maybe mean `pg_locks`?

Comment: You are right, there was a custom view in our database, i edited the answer.

Comment: In my case, your `pg_cancel_backend` in combination with the qeury here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10317371/301277 allowed me to remove all "forgotten" locks. Thanks!

Comment: to kill type "SELECT pg_cancel_backend(pid) FROM active_locks;" instead

Comment: use "SELECT pg_terminate_backend('pid')"  to kill forcefully

Comment: When I run pg_cancel_backend , I get the error: "ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "pid""

Comment: This answer saved our production installation.

Comment: `pg_cancel_backend` did not worked for me, but `pg_terminate_backend` did.

Answer (score 60):

**Simple:**

*Get the active locks from pg_locks:*

```sql
SELECT t.relname, l.locktype, page, virtualtransaction, pid, mode, granted
FROM pg_locks l, pg_stat_all_tables t 
WHERE l.relation = t.relid 
ORDER BY relation asc;
```

*Copy the pid(ex: 14210) from above result and substitute in the below command.*

```sql
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(14210)
```

Comment: `pg_cancel_backend(14210)` will cancel the query with a `SIGINT` vs a `SIGTERM`, [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html) `pg_terminate_backend(14210)` would terminate the session as well as the query.

Answer (score 34):

To release possible locks from Postgres I generally follow these in sequence.

1. Find long-running queries in your DB by running the following query. This will help you fetch the PIDs of the long-running query which is blocking your update.

   ```
   SELECT
   pid,
   now() - pg_stat_activity.query_start AS duration,
   query,
   state
   FROM pg_stat_activity
   WHERE (now() - pg_stat_activity.query_start) > interval '5 minutes';
   ```
2. or if you can find out which processes are holding a lock on a particular table by running this query

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM pg_locks l
   JOIN pg_class t ON l.relation = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r'
   WHERE t.relname = 'Bill';
   ```
3. Once you figure out the PID which is 'active' and blocking your update you can kill it by running this query. It takes some time to kill the process.

   ```
   SELECT pg_cancel_backend(__pid__);
   ```
4. Check by running Query 2 if the process is killed. If it still is active then kill this process by running this query.

   ```
   SELECT pg_terminate_backend(__pid__);
   ```

Answer (score 17):

This will clear all locks on all tables.

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
    FROM pg_stat_activity
    WHERE pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

Use with caution on production databases.

Answer (score -7):

i've never worked with PostreSql but if it's similar to others i'd say you have to kill the connection/end the transaction that's holding the locks.