# psql database -# vs =#

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a docker container that I have created a table in called "first_app_firstresource." When I try, however, to delete this table, it does nothing. Instead, this is what happens:

```
docker=# \d
```

Part of the table...

`Schema |         Name           | Type  | Owner
    --------------------------------------------
public | first_app_firstresource | table | docker`

then it goes straight to...

```
docker-#
```

Notice now instead of =#, it is now -#.

I then try to drop the table with

```
docker-# drop table first_app_firstresource
```

and nothing whatsoever happens.

I have seen [Postgresql DROP TABLE doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317114/postgresql-drop-table-doesnt-work), and adding quotes doesn't seem to do anything, either.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#R2-APP-PSQL-4

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the copy and paste of the entire `psql` session, not just snippets?

Comment: Great, I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026/in-psql-why-do-some-commands-have-no-effect to be very useful!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In psql you need to end your SQL commands with a semicolon.  The prompt `-#` means that it waiting for you to do so.  I also suspect you have inserted some stray characters between the `\d` and `drop table`.  So when you do add the semicolon, you will probably get a syntax error, because the command you sent is not what you think.  I do this all the time, getting a stray `ls` into my psql commands.