# Postgres Database locked: Queries running forever

Tags: postgresql

One of my python scripts ran some ALTER TABLE queries on the Postgres database. Something wrong happened and the tables got locked. When I run any query on any of those tables, it tells me Query Running and nothing happens.
Currently, I am able to remove this lock only by shutting down my system and restarting it. Please tell me a better method. This is a Windows host.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should check for locks:

```
SELECT l.*,a.*
  FROM pg_locks l
  JOIN pg_stat_activity a USING (pid)
 WHERE NOT granted;
```

You'll see a list of *waiting* sessions.  And the following:

```
SELECT l.*,a.*
  FROM pg_locks l
  JOIN pg_stat_activity a USING (pid)
 WHERE granted
   AND (database,relation) IN (SELECT database,relation
                                 FROM pg_locks WHERE NOT granted);
```

will give you a list of *blocking* sessions. If you use [`psql`, use `expanded` output](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html) to get column-per-row output, better to view such information.

[The following SQL script](https://github.com/dataegret/pg-utils/blob/master/sql/locktree.sql) will display blocking tree (if there are blocked sessions), sessions on the top of each branch (yes, quite often there're several branches) will be the blocking ones.

I advise you to also have a look at [this wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_dependency_information) and this question: [Postgresql DROP TABLE doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317114/postgresql-drop-table-doesnt-work) 
(though it speaks bout `DROP TABLE` there, it might help).

In your case, I recommend to identify *blocking* sessions and try to find out *why* they're blocking. Most typical case in my experience — somebody forgot to press enter after `COMMIT` and went out for lunch. If you're sure this will not hurt your system, you can kill *blocking* session:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid);
```

Comment: Yes. The cause was query not committed.

Answer (score 6):

[Reference taken from this article.](http://www.dbrnd.com/2015/09/script-to-find-sessions-that-are-blocking-other-sessions-in-postgresql/)
**Find blocking sessions:**

```
    SELECT 
        pl.pid as blocked_pid
        ,psa.usename as blocked_user
        ,pl2.pid as blocking_pid
        ,psa2.usename as blocking_user
        ,psa.query as blocked_statement
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_locks pl
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity psa
        ON pl.pid = psa.pid
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_locks pl2
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity psa2
        ON pl2.pid = psa2.pid
        ON pl.transactionid = pl2.transactionid 
            AND pl.pid != pl2.pid
    WHERE NOT pl.granted;
```