# PostgreSQL find locks including the table name

Tags: relational-database, postgresql-9.2, database-administration

I'm trying to take a look at locks that are happening on
specific tables in my PostgreSQL database.

I see there's a table called pg_locks

```
select * from pg_locks;
```

Which seems to give me a bunch of columns but is it possible
to find the relation because I see one of the columns is
the relation oid.

What table must I link that to to get the relation name?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23060492/9843399 for a quick query to add a more user-friendly lock view

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this :

```
select nspname,relname,l.* from pg_locks l join pg_class c on 
 (relation=c.oid) join pg_namespace nsp on (c.relnamespace=nsp.oid) where 
  pid in (select procpid from pg_stat_activity where 
  datname=current_database() and current_query!=current_query())
```

Answer (score 18):

This is Remy's query, adjusted for Postgres 10:

```
select nspname, relname, l.* 
from pg_locks l 
    join pg_class c on (relation = c.oid) 
    join pg_namespace nsp on (c.relnamespace = nsp.oid)
where pid in (select pid 
              from pg_stat_activity
              where datname = current_database() 
                and query != current_query());
```

Answer (score 14):

If you just want the contents of `pg_locks` but with a human-friendly relation name,

```sql
select relation::regclass, * from pg_locks;
```

Answer (score 5):

**The below command will give the list of locks:**

```
select t.relname,l.locktype,page,virtualtransaction,pid,mode,granted 
from pg_locks l, pg_stat_all_tables t where l.relation=t.relid
order by relation asc;
```

Answer (score 4):

Remy Baron's answer is correct I just wanted to post one I came up
with as well only because it's more specific to what I need in this case

```
select pg_class.relname,
       pg_locks.mode
from pg_class,
     pg_locks
where pg_class.oid = pg_locks.relation
and pg_class.relnamespace >= 2200
;
```

Comment: `pg_class.relnamespace >= 2200` it seems here that `2200` is the "magic" number I was looking for to exclude non-interesting postgres internal locks from the list and return only locks on user-defined tables. I wonder if there's some way to introspect this number from postgres itself?