# Postgres - select for update timeout and lock monitoring

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I perform `SELECT FOR UPDATE` in my app. 
What happens if row will not be updated and no writes for this row will perform, how long this lock will exists?

And is it possible to monitor such rows (rows selected for update)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063043/how-to-release-possible-postgres-row-locks/23060492

Comment: In normal cases, until the end of the transaction.

Comment: What do you mean by monitor?

Comment: For example count and duration of locks. lexicore anwswer this questions above.

Comment: Yes - but we're talking about locks, not rows acquired by lock as you write in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not DBA and maybe write something wrong, but `SELECT FOR UPDATE` locks rows, that's what about my question. You can suggest improvement.